# Overwrite ONE column in select statement with a fixed value without listing all columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number of tables with a large number of columns (> 100) in a SQL Server database. In some cases when selecting (using views) I need to replace exactly ONE of the columns with a fixed result value instead of the data from the row(s).
Is there a way to use something like

```
select table.*, 'value' as Column1 from table
```

if Column1 is a column name within the table?

Of course I can list all the columns which are expected as result in the select Statement, replacing the one with a value.
However, this is very inconvinient and having 3 or 4 those views I have to maintain them all if columns are added or removed from the table.

Comment: did u try using update present table? instead of replacing

Comment: No, this is not possible.  You need to list all of the columns explicitly to do that,

Comment: Unless you have a very good reason for doing otherwise, you should *always* explicitly state all columns. Using `SELECT * ...` can have various unintended consequences.

Comment: This would be very useful for temporary queries that is made to just run a quick report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you have to specify columns in this case. 
And you have much more serious problems if tables are being changed often. This may be a signal of large architectural defects. 
Anyway, listing all columns instead of `*` is a good practice, because if columns number *will* change, it may cause cascade errors.

Comment: that's what I expected :-(
I will Keep the question open for some more time, maybe there are some recommendations. 
And I can tell you, there ARE good reasons to NOT list all columns...

Comment: @Herbert so maybe you will share them with the community here?

Comment: The application at hand implements the delivery of XML Messages following the "ONIX for books" Standard. It is a way for Publishers, wholesalers and bookshops to exchanged bibliografic and Status Information about books. The entire Standard consists of about 500-600 data elements, implemented in 12 or more tables. The Standard is expanded and upgraded continuosly according to market Needs, so is the implementation with respect to the German market where I am working in. I have to add data elements (=columns) to the tables as Need arises. ... to be continued

Comment: To complicate it more, different expressions Need different sets of columns or slightly different values in the same column. Therefore, using "select *" instead of repeating lists of 150 and more columns in 5 or more different places is just an economical way of implementation. The application itself is driven by a data dictionary which selects the needed columns for each specific Output ...

Comment: @miracle_the_V This is an old question, but to simplify @Herbert's response: using `*` in a `select` statement makes it less brittle. If you want to be able to modify underlying tables without breaking stored procedures, wildcards are an excellent choice.

Answer (score 0):

As other responses have noted, this can't be done in a single statement. There is a workaround, however, which is not perfect but does circumvent the need to list columns manually: save your initial, unmodified query to a temp table, `update` the column(s) you need to overwrite, then `select` the results:

```
--we're going to use a temp table; make sure it doesn't already exist
if (object_id('tempdb..#tmpTbl') is not null)
    drop table #tmpTbl

--initial query to retrieve all the columns
select *
into #tmpTbl
from TblWithManycolumns

--update column(s) from another table or query
update #tmpTbl
set ColToBeReplaced = trv.ColWithReplacementValue
from #tmpTbl t
join TableWithReplacementValue trv
    on trv.KeyCol = t.KeyCol
--where trv.FilterCol = @FilterVal -- if needed

--this select contains the final output data
select * from #tmpTbl
drop table #tmpTbl
```

This has plenty of drawbacks. Complexity, performance, etc. But it is very flexible and solves the major problem of preventing changes to the main table (`TblWithManyColumns`) from breaking the query or requiring manual changes. This is particularly important if you're trying to generate SQL.